# Wavenumbers of cyclic ketones

Tags: organic-chemistry, carbonyl-compounds, ir-spectroscopy

Rank the compounds below in order of increasing C=O absorption frequency in IR spectrum (top - lowest wavenumber, bottom - highest wavenumber):
[image]

Question: Would I count compound #1's cyclopentane or all 11 carbons because wavenumber increases with 5C or smaller rings.

If I count #1 as a cyclopentane for this purpose then #3 has the lowest wavenumber and #2 has the highest.

Comment: related: [Ring Strain and C=O Stretching Frequency](https://chemistry.stackexchange.com/questions/16473/ring-strain-and-c-o-stretching-frequency)

Answer (score 1):

Here is nice comparison of all 3 ring sizes. Octahydro-1H-inden-1-one (either *cis*- or *trans*-) carbonyl strechings fall between cyclohexanone and cyclobutanone, thus, fused ring is not a factor (it is to some extend because of sunstitution).

[image: IR image]

Answer (score 0):

#1  Octahydro-1H-inden-1-one C=O stretch from [reference](http://actachemscand.org/pdf/acta_vol_17_p0738-0748.pdf)

cis 1730 $\text{cm}^{-1}$
[image]

trans 1754 $\text{cm}^{-1}$
[image]

#2 - Cyclobutanone [NIST Listing](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?ID=C1191953&Mask=8) C=O stretch at 1790 $\text{cm}^{-1}$ from [spectra](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/inchi?Scan=cob10190&Type=IR)

#3 - Cyclohexanone [NIST Listing](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C108941&Mask=4&Type=ANTOINE&Plot=on) C=O stretch at 1740 $\text{cm}^{-1}$ from [spectra](http://webbook.nist.gov/cgi/cbook.cgi?ID=C108941&Type=IR-SPEC&Index=0#IR-SPEC)

Comment: #1 doesn't have stereochemistry here @MaxW

Comment: interesting, but unhelpful and unpedagogic.